# i simply cannot get libreoffice to load on new system 76

Tags: apt, package-management, libreoffice

I have a new System76 and I needed to load a braille font that can only be loaded on openoffice. So after deleting Libreoffice I tried to instal open office, and I simply do not have the knowledge to do that. So many problems, no tutorial helped. Sites in cut & Paste commands could not establish a connection, etc . . . Now I am just trying to put libre back in it and I have done everything the instructions say. Downloaded the DEB, extracted it and when I go to install it, I get:

```
Kudu:~$ cd ~/Downloads/LibreOffice_5.2.0.x_Linux_x86_deb/DEBS
bash: cd: /home/lem/Downloads/LibreOffice_5.2.0.x_Linux_x86_deb/DEBS: No such file or directory
```

I am copying and pasting the directory location right from the 
Download folder. It always says it cannot find the directory. 
what can I do to get the computer to recognize the package. This is beyond frustrating. I clearly was not ready to be a linux user. Very frustrating. Thank you for any help you might impart on this situation

Comment: On an ubuntu system, you can simply `sudo apt install libreoffice-common`

Comment: Your problem started when you decided to remove libre for open office. Those two are basically the same software and due to license problems libre office will be more developed. And DON'T download DEBS. Use ubuntu software center to install libre office. That braille font will work in libre office the same way it would in open office too.

Comment: "This is beyond frustrating. I clearly was not ready to be a linux user. Very frustrating" Wrong attitude. Why do you expect a new OS to work for you from the 1st moment? I bet it took you years to get the hang of Windows. You just don't want to remember it. -THINK- 1st then act.

Answer (score 0):

1st off: forget about your problem and please install libreoffice from Ubuntu software center or command line and make sure it works.

So either open software center, search for "libre office" and install it or ...

```
sudo apt install libreoffice-common
```

---

**About the font**

in general you copy that font over to `/usr/share/font/` (for system wide fonts) or `/home/$USER/.local/fonts`(for 1 user only) and libreoffice will gladly pick it up for you.

If that does not work for you please edit your question and add the location where you found the font.